# How to get Material color with Autodesk Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I'm trying to get the material of a fragment in Forge Viewer.
I tried calling `NOP_VIEWER.impl.getMaterial(fragId)` but returned nothing.
Viewer `matman().materials` returns all materials, but I don't know how to get the right material of the current fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the material assigned to a specific geometry/fragment through the `FragmentList` class and its `getMaterial(fragid)` method, for example, like so:

```js
function getObjectMaterials(dbid, model) {
    const tree = model.getInstanceTree();
    const frags = model.getFragmentList();
    tree.enumNodeFragments(dbid, function (fragid) {
        const material = frags.getMaterial(fragid);
        console.log('Object', dbid, 'has material', material);
    }, true);
}
```